# shell script command error

Tags: shell, cpu

I try executing the CPU monitoring script below, and the script throws an error.  But direct execution of `top -bn1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | awk '{print$2}' | sed -e 's/%us,//g'` does not throw an error.  Can someone help here??

```
 if (top -bn1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | awk '{print$2}' | sed -e 's/%us,//g') -gt 1 ; then
     echo ('CPU percentage is $CPU_PER, which is higher than 50%. Kindly login to server and validate the process.')
 else 
     echo  ('Executing Else statement.')
 fi
```

Comment: Can you tell us which shell are you using bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what shell you're using but if you use Bash the commands would look like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

# ... code ...

op=$(top -bn1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | awk '{print$2}' | sed -e 's/%us,//g')
if [ "y" = "$(echo | awk "($op > 1) { print \"y\"; }")" ]; then
    echo 'CPU Percentage is grater Which is Highere than 50% Kindly Login to server and validate the process' 
else 
    echo  'Excuting Else statement ' 
fi
```

Also, since `$(top -bn1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | awk '{print$2}' | sed -e 's/%us,//g')` doesn't always return a whole number, a normal `-gt` does not work. That's why I used `awk` in this example. It could also be done with `bc` but since not all distributions have that command pre-installed, I think the version above is the best in this case.

And here is the plain code for validating:

```
#!/bin/bash
op=$(top -bn1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | awk '{print$2}' | sed -e 's/%us,//g')
num=1
if [ "y" = "$(echo | awk "($op > $num) { print \"y\"; }")" ]; then
    printf "\n${op} is bigger than ${num}\n\n"
else 
    printf "\n${op} is smaller than ${num}\n\n"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks NullDev..

However i get this below error

./CPU_Monirot.sh: line 3: [[: 3.6: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".6")

i see the output result for the top -bn1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | awk '{print$2}' | sed -e 's/%us,//g' is 3.6

Answer (score 0):

With less fuss, `awk` can do the parsing, the decimal comparison, and then output an *exit status*.  Any code with a *true/false exit status*  can be used after an `if` or before a `&&`:

```
top -bn1 | awk 'NR == 3 { f=($2 > 1) } END{exit !f}'  && echo "yadda yadda"
```

The `awk` code checks only the 3rd line: `NR == 3`; then compares the second item to *1*: `($2 > 1)`; and stores that *true/false* value in `f`, and outputs the logical NOT of that, `exit !f`, so the unix shell understands.

Output:

```
yadda yadda
```

Adding a `print` to the `awk` code allows storing the value to a shell variable `$n` at the same time:

```
if n=$(top -bn1 | \
       awk 'NR == 3 { print $2 ; f=($2 > 1) } END{exit !f}') ; \
then echo "$n > 1" ; else echo "$n <= 1" ; fi
```

Output (on my system):

```
18.6 > 1
```